# Add elements with information of an array in Jquery with delay of some moments

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of some data, which I want to append in a Div at runtime and want that data to show with animation in slow motion.

```
offers.forEach(function (offer) {
   $("#result_area").append("<div class='alert bg-pink'>" + offer + "</div>");
});
```

I am using this code to append my data into `#result_area` div, it is working fine but loading complete data in a moment, whereas I want to show data 1 by 1 with some moments break.

Comment: use jquery fadeIn() animation

Comment: He'd have to use `appendTo()` instead of `append()` then.

Comment: any of the animation which I am applying is working with the outer/main div, but not working separately with inner div which I am adding.

Comment: You'll have to use `appendTo()` instead of `append()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery's [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
offers.forEach(function (offer) {
   $("#result_area").delay( 1000 , "divQueue" ).append("<div class='alert bg-pink'>" + offer + "</div>");
});
```

Or use `setTimeout` with a `counter`

```
counter = 0;
offers.forEach(function (offer) {
   setTimeout( function(){
       $("#result_area").delay( 1000 , "divQueue" ).append("<div class='alert bg-pink'>" + offer + "</div>");
   }, (++counter * 1000) );
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var offers = [
  ["offer1", "10"],
  ["offer2", "20"],
  ["offer3", "30"],
  ["offer4", "40"],
  ["offer5", "50"],
  ["offer6", "60"],
  ["offer1", "70"],
  ["offer1", "80"]
];
for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#result_area").append("<div class='innerdiv'><h4 style='float:left'>" + offers[i][0] + "</h4><h4 style='float:right'> " + offers[i][1] + "</h4></div>");
  }, (i * 500));

}
```

```css
.innerdiv {
  height: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result_area">

</div>
```

Comment: This is also adding data in one shot.

Comment: @Anandagrawal Please check both the options.

Comment: The same thing is not working with for Loop, var counter = 0;
                for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#result_area").append("<div class='alert bg-pink'><h4 style='float:left'>" + top_offers[i][0] + "</h4>-<h4 style='float:right'> " + top_offers[i][1] + "</h4></div>");
                    }, (++counter * 500));

                } actually it showing the data of last index all time.

Comment: why are you using `counter` when you already have `i` and vice-versa? Also specify the exact behavior instead of saying "Not working".

Comment: I tried with both, counter and 'i', I mentioned at last that it is showing only last indexed data all 5 times.

Comment: @Anandagrawal But you had mentioned above that my code had worked. Can you share a fiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163690/discussion-between-anand-agrawal-and-gurvinder372).

Comment: For me on Google Chrome, they are appearing one by one.

Comment: @Anandagrawal Added a demo for you. Please tell me if you are getting correct output.

Comment: Yeah it is showing one by one, but giving wrong data, please check.

Comment: @Anandagrawal Got it now... check the update... use let instead of var

Comment: Thanks a lot @gurvinder.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout` .

```js
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   setTimeout(function() {
     $("#result_area").append("<div class='alert bg-pink'>" + "offer your value" + "</div>");
  }, i * 500, i); 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='result_area'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Jquery's .show to animate which should do the trick. Check [Jquery .show link](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

For the code snippet you gave, try this:

```
offers.forEach(function (offer) {
   $("#result_area").append("<div class='alert bg-pink'>" + offer + "</div>").show("slow");
});
```

Some Examples:

```
$("#element).show(4000);
$("#element).show("slow");
$("#element).show("fast");
```